# Acquiring Dutch Passport

Tags: netherlands, passport, south-african-citizens

My father was born in the Netherlands but at the time of my birth (1989 in RSA) he was no longer a Dutch Citizen, is there any hope for me getting a Dutch passport? Please help.

**EDIT:**

My father left the Netherlands when he was two and, as I mentioned before, lost his citizenship by naturalising in RSA when he was 39, can he not regain his citizenship via the Option procedure? (See condition 5 under 'who can apply' in [Option procedure](https://ind.nl/en/dutch-citizenship/pages/option.aspx)) If he regains his Dutch citizenship, I can in turn, receive mine if he acknowledges me (we would need to provide DNA evidence according to [Dutch citizenship by birth/acknowledgement](https://ind.nl/en/dutch-citizenship/pages/by-birth-or-acknowledgement.aspx)). Does this all sound plausible?

Comment: Did your father lose his Dutch nationality by naturalizing in South Africa (or another country)?  If so, how old was he when he naturalized?

Comment: Yes he lost it by naturalizing in South Africa. He was about 39 when he did this.

Comment: In that case, the first comment would appear to be correct. @Traveller, would you like to post it as a proper answer?

Comment: With regard to your edit, your father would have to move to the Netherlands for one year before being able to exercise the option procedure.  But even if he did, that would not change your citizenship because he won't have been a Dutch citizen when you were born. The page you link to is somewhat imprecise about this, but acknowledgement normally only applies to children born out of wedlock. Furthermore, the [law itself](https://wetten.overheid.nl/BWBR0003738/2018-08-01) suggests that this route only exists for minor children over the age of 7.

Comment: There's another possibility: it used to be the case that a woman married to a Dutch man was automatically Dutch.  I believe this changed in 1963, but I am not certain of the date.  If your mother and father married before the change, and he naturalized in South Africa after the change, it is perhaps possible that she retained her Dutch nationality.  If *she* was a Dutch citizen when you were born, then you may have received Dutch nationality from her, in which case you might yourself be former Dutch. But if I'm right about the change being in 1963, this seems unlikely indeed.

Comment: Hi Phoog, thank you for help, not many people are willing to assist me. I like your latter suggestion, do you know who I could possibly contact in RSA or abroad to find out if the law was still in effect when my parents married?

Comment: The standard answer of course would be a Dutch immigration lawyer, but I have found that they sometimes do not understand the finer points of historic changes in the law -- they're more oriented toward the current state of the law as it applies to new immigrants. The rule had definitely changed by 1976 (the last change to the 1892 law before it was repealed in 1985, available at https://pvmarkus.home.xs4all.nl/wet.htm). Between '76 and '85 a woman who was married to a Dutch man could become Dutch only by declaration to the appropriate authorities.

Comment: If your parents married during that period and your mother made no such declaration, then she was not Dutch.  This route was removed in 1985, so she also would not have been Dutch if they were married after then.  If they were married in or before 1976, let me know when it was and I'll try to find out whether any relevant amendments were passed between then and 1976.

Comment: They were definitely married before 1979. I will find out if she made a declaration and the exact year of marriage. Thanks for your assistance Phoog.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Phoog. They were married in 1977. So are you then sure that my mother couldn't have been Dutch by virtue of this marriage?

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you mention that your father lost his Dutch nationality by naturalizing in South Africa when he was about 39. In the circumstances you describe, it would appear that your only option to get a Dutch passport would be through naturalization after having lived in the Netherlands for 5 years

https://www.government.nl/topics/dutch-nationality/becoming-a-dutch-national

Note that if a South African citizen does not obtain prior permission to retain their South African citizenship they will automatically lose it on voluntary acquisition of a foreign citizenship. https://www.sahc.org.au/citizenship/Dual_Citizenship.htm